# Ubuntu server and ubuntu with netbeans remote connection: upload permission denied

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, netbeans

I have a project on a remote server (ubuntu server 15.04). I can download my files from `/var/www/html` with no problem. But I can't change and reupload them. I get permission denied when renaming a dir or file, upload a new file or deleting an existing file.

I make my connection with SFTP and I start Netbeans from the terminal with `sudo`. I also checked Preserve remote File Permissions in the Run configuration.

As a last resort I have installed `vsftpd` on the web server and followed steps to add a user. Again, connecting with the user credentials and downloading works fine but uploading doesn't at all.

My goal is to connect as a user with enough permissions to change or upload new files and directories but preserve the orginal permissions on the server.

Can anybody shed some light on my problem?

thanks
Thomas

EDIT:

Maybe some more (useful?) information: the files and directories are owned by the user `root` from the group `root`. The CMS is Drupal 8.0.1

Comment: Yes. It *"might"* be a problem. If you are connecting using different user then `root`, and want to write files that are owned by root, it is not possible. Have a look for some linux permissions description. Correct way would be that the files in your document root would be owned by the user you are using to upload the data. They do not need to be root-owned.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jakuje. My user that I upload with belongs to the group 'Root'. I will look into it asap this week and report my findings. Thanks again

Comment: Ha Jakuje, thank you very much. It amazes me that I didn't think of that before. I changed the owner and group of the project on the webserver to the one I have on my local drive for that project.  `sudo chown -R username:group directory`. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much. It amazes me that I didn't think of that before. I changed the owner and group of the project on the webserver to the one I have on my local drive for that project. `sudo chown -R username:group directory`. Worked like a charm. Thanks!